# Zookeeper doesn't work with JRE installed on 32 bit Windows

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have installed JRE on a 32-bit Windows machine and trying to run Zookeeper.
It shows following error:

```
Error: missing `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
```

**Versions used:**

*KAFAKA/Zookeeper:* kafka_2.11-1.1.0

*JRE:* jre1.8.0_181

I tried to use server folder from 64-bit machine but obviously it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have `Program Files (x86)`, which implies that you have a 64bit machine, so why do you need 32bit Java? Kafka doesn't have good Windows support anyway

Comment: Ohh, that folder is just because I cloned 64 machine to 32 bit. Anyways editing the question, please ignore.

Comment: I think you'll be having more than just Java issues if you clone one CPU architecture into another machine

Answer (score 1):

You need a server JRE, which you can acquire and install from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html

You can however hack around this (dirty, don't do this if you have no need to do so):
In your C:\Program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_181\bin

Here create a new folder "Server"

Copy everything from the C:\Program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\client folder into the new Server folder.

Comment: Thanks @fl0w, but when I checked this link, there is no 32-version for Windows available to download.

Comment: That's because Oracle does not offer 32 bit server jres (for a good reason), why don't you just use the 64 bit version?

Comment: That's because I am developing an on-premise solution and want to support both 32/64-bit OS customers.

Comment: @Baby What do you mean "customers"? Are you installing Kafka on Windows for people? If so, and you're installing from scratch, why Windows?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am installing Kafka on Windows for people and requirement is to install it on Windows.

Comment: @BabyDuck Alright, well, until Kafka gets proper testing support frameworks for Windows, good luck with running that in production, that is all